# Using SpatiaLite with web2py?

Tags: python, web2py, spatialite

As explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32402598/adapter-does-not-support-geometry-exception-when-declaring-geometry-field), I've been attempting to use the web2py database abstraction layer's SpatiaLite adapter, and I'm receiving a "RuntimeError: Failure to connect, tried 5 times" message.

I've installed the SpatiaLite DLLs into Windows' /System32 folder, and I'm able to do the following:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
conn.enable_load_extension(True)
conn.execute('SELECT load_extension("libspatialite-2.dll")')

SpatiaLite version ..: 2.2      Supported Extensions:
        - 'VirtualShape'        [direct Shapefile access]
        - 'VirtualText'         [direct CSV/TXT access]
        - 'RTree'               [Spatial Index - R*Tree]
        - 'MbrCache'            [Spatial Index - MBR cache]
        - 'SpatiaLite'          [Spatial SQL - OGC]
PROJ.4 Rel. 4.6.1, 21 August 2008
GEOS version 3.0.0-CAPI-1.4.1
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x0202B360>
```

So it appears that my python installation can use SpatiaLite. However, the presence of the SpatiaLite DLLs doesn't seem to resolve the web2py "Failure to connect" error. Any suggestions on how to get SpatiaLite working with web2py?

Comment: Are you running web2py from source or are you using the Windows binary version?

Comment: @Anthony - I'm running the source version of web2py, not the Windows binary version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, it looks like you have to [rename the DLL](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/web2py/hIs2qtuS4Ls/FE3ZN6qJmDMJ) to `libspatialite.dll`.

Comment: Note, [issue filed](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/issues/1062) requesting removal of the name change requirement.

Comment: Yep, that took care of it. Thank you